# How To call a function inside of a struct inside of another function

Tags: c++, struct, void

I know this is going to sound very dumb but I'm attempting something weird

**CODE**

```
void something() {
    struct x {
        auto random(int x, int y) {
            return x + y;
        }
    }; 
    x theStruct;
}
```

I am aware that this looks random but is there a way that i could declare `x theStruct;` and call it outside of the function it is inside

**EXAMPLE**

```
void something() {
    struct x {
        auto random(int x, int y) {
            return x + y;
        }
    };
    x theStruct;
}

void anotherfunc() {
    theStruct.random();
}
```

I'm also not sure if the syntax is 100% correct since I'm writing this in stack overflow,
any help would be amazing

Comment: `theStruct` is a local variable, so no, you can't access it from outside the function it's declared in.

Comment: Short answer: No.  If you want to use the struct in multiple places, move it into a common scope.

Comment: In general, no, this is not possible. `theStruct` is local to `something()` and it cannot be accessed outside of that function. If you tell us more about the context of your question (why do you want that?) then we may be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: you have some missing `;`. Its just typos but in combination with weird intendation it makes the code very hard to read

Comment: You can't access that variable, but you can return a copy of it from the function and use that (`something().random()`), if you use `auto` generously.

Comment: I suppose also missing `return` was a typo, fixed that, just rollback if I misinterpreted

Comment: If this code is intended to be literal, random() has no state. You could consider making it a static method, which would allow you to call it without creating an instance. But you still have the problem of it being defined locally to something()

Comment: What would it mean if you called `something` twice and had two different `theStruct` variables?  What if you hadn’t called it at all?

Comment: is there an actual reason you want to do that? Some underlying problem that maybe can be solved in a different way? (
[XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))